# Insert some structured custom HTML in DOM simply using JS

Tags: javascript

With JQuery i had this :

```
 let searchHeader= $(".block-amu-search-form__title");
 let closeButton = "<div class=\"callout\" data-closable>\n" +
          "  <button class=\"close-button\" aria-label=\"Close alert\" type=\"button\" data-close>\n" +
          "    <span aria-hidden=\"true\">&times;</span>\n" +
          "  </button>\n" +
          "</div>"
     
 searchHeader.append(closeButton);
```

How to convert in JS ?

```
 let searchHeader= document.querySelector(".block-amu-search-form__title");
 let closeButton = "<div class=\"callout\" data-closable>\n" +
          "  <button class=\"close-button\" aria-label=\"Close alert\" type=\"button\" data-close>\n" +
          "    <span aria-hidden=\"true\">&times;</span>\n" +
          "  </button>\n" +
          "</div>"          
 searchHeader.append(closeButton);
```

This insert the button as a string and appendChild required a node object

Comment: `searchHeader.innerHTML = searchHeader.innerHTML + closeButton;`? Your passing a string to Element.append  so it treats it as a string. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/append

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to append a string to an html element. you should do this instead

```js
let searchHeader = document.querySelector(".block-amu-search-form__title");
let closeButton = "<div class=\"callout\" data-closable>\n" +
    "  <button class=\"close-button\" aria-label=\"Close alert\" type=\"button\" data-close>\n" +
    "    <span aria-hidden=\"true\">&times;</span>\n" +
    "  </button>\n" +
    "</div>"
const buttonContainer = document.createElement('div');
buttonContainer.innerHTML = closeButton;
searchHeader.append(buttonContainer);
```

or just simply

```js
let searchHeader = document.querySelector(".block-amu-search-form__title");
let closeButton = "<div class=\"callout\" data-closable>\n" +
    "  <button class=\"close-button\" aria-label=\"Close alert\" type=\"button\" data-close>\n" +
    "    <span aria-hidden=\"true\">&times;</span>\n" +
    "  </button>\n" +
    "</div>"
searchHeader.innerHTML = searchHeader.innerHTML + closeButton;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're working with vanilla js then why not just use innerHtml?

> document.getElementById("block-amu-search-form__title").innerHTML = closeButton;

you can refer to it. [Here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_innerhtml.asp)